# nHibernate order by N with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, sql-order-by

With a SQL Query I can `order by` N, where N is a column index. For example

```
 SELECT name, salary FROM employee ORDER BY 2;
```

How can I do this with nHibernate?

Comment: Ordering by ordinals is a bad habit - if the order of columns changes, so does your ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. NHibernate [`order by`](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-ordering) clause requires property names (aliases) and / or expressions to be specified.

Comment: so I need fluent hibernate? (not that I know what that is)

Comment: Fluent NHibernate is just a way to declare mappings for your entities without resorting to XML; it has nothing to do with HQL's `order by`. You cannot (nor should you as `rexem` rightly pointed out above) order by ordinals in HQL.